# Code::Blocks & WxWidgets Matching Release configuration

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

I am attempting to start a new project in Code:: Blocks (v17.12) using WxWidgets (v3.1.3) on Windows (10).

(For context, I am new to compiling- I'm a script coder trying to branch out.  So... don't be afraid to talk to me like I'm an idiot.  I'm prepared to accept that possibility.)

I downloaded the official 3.1.3 source, expanded it to "D:\code\wxw"
I successfully compiled it using mingw32-make that came with Code::Blocks-- there is a directory "D:\code\wxw\build\msw\gcc_mswudll" and "D:\code\wxw\lib\gcc_dll", the latter containing .dll files.

So I go into code blocks, and I:

Create New Project -> wxWidgets Project
Select wxWidgets 3.1.x
Project Title "HelloWorld", under D:\code\C++\tinker-- everything else autofilled.
Project details-- my info.

Preferred GUI Builder - None.  Application Type - Dialog.

wxWidgets' location:  D:\code\wxw

Compiler: GNU GCC 
Selected "Create Release Configuration" because that's how it was compiled.

It provides an Output dir of "bin\Release\" and an Objects output dir of "obj\Release\", which I do not change.

Selected use DLL, built as monolithic, and enable Unicode-- the latter matching my compile settings.

When I click next, it tells me "A Matching Release configuration cannot be found in the wxWidgets directory you specified.  This means that the Release target of your project will not build."

I've found multiple hits searching on this error message, but they all devolve into discussions of monolithic vs polylithic compiling and critique of other compiler settings and not actually addressing the problem.

EDIT:

Based on http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=WxWindowsQuickRef

I used the following settings for compiling.  I set them in config.gcc

BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 CXXFLAGS=-fno-keep-inline-dllexport

Comment: There is a mismatch between the options that you passed to mingw32-make and the settings you specified in the wizard.  Can you post the full mingw32-make command you used to build the library.

Comment: mingw32-make.exe -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 CXXFLAGS=-fno-keep-inline-dllexport

is the data you are looking for, but I actually changed in in config.gcc

Comment: @CatherSteincamp, for you future reference - using `MONOLITHIC=1` while (still) supported might give you problems in the long run. It is better and easier to avoid it. Also it doesn't give you any gains. Using `SHARED=1` is also kind of weird - usually on Windows the static build is preferred, because then you don't have to supply the wxWidgets library alone with your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important page of the wizard is the 8th page.  Based on the settings you gave above, it should look exactly like this:

[image]

Also, instead of giving the path on the 6th page, I would define a global variable named `wx` in codeblocks like this:

[image]

Then on the 6th page, you would enter `$(#wx)` instead of the actual path.  This will make using your projects much easier if you ever upgrade the wxWidgets library.  You'll only need to change the location in the global variable settings.

Comment: Page 8 was exactly as the picture.  

Using $(#wx), on the other hand, seems to be what fixed it.  

Thanks!